# How to use values from 2 item collections?

Tags: 2010, development, linq

I'm trying to use values from 2 `SPListItemCollection`s, as one of them have a lookup field with values from the other list.

The reason why I need to do this, is because I need the value from the other list in order to OrderBy correctly when populating the values.

This is what I have so far.

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPList list1 = web.Lists["List1"];
SPList list2 = web.Lists["List2"];

foreach (var l1 in list1.Items.Cast<SPListItem>().OrderBy(l1 => l1["Category"]).ThenBy(l1 => l1["Position"]))
{
    /* Logic */
}
```

I want **l1["Category"]** to be replaced by a column name from **list2**.
How can I achieve this?

*I'm not that experienced with "advanced" coding.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is look into [CAML field joins and projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975%28office.14%29.aspx)

As the name suggests, it allows you to join two lists linked by a lookup field, and bring up the values through a single CAML query. The page linked above is not a beacon of clarity but you can find good examples on Google.

Using CAML will also enable you to put your Order by in it. A CAML query will also be more efficient than your current list1.Items.Cast<..>( )

Note also that using

```
web.Lists["List1"];
```

can be slow if you have many lists on that web. Consider using something like

```
web.GetList(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.ServerRelativeUrl, "MyListUrl"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by Join and Projected fields. Please check the section **3. List Joins** here : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/19/rdbms-features-sharepoint-2010/